# doctrine2 subtraction of sub-query values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine

I would like to run the following query with doctrine, can anyone help?

```
SELECT SUM(col_a) -
       (SELECT SUM(col_b) FROM tab_b WHERE user_id=1)
FROM tab_a
WHERE user_id=1
```

thanks

Comment: Correct me if I be mistaken, but can't you just write this as a difference of two sum queries?

Comment: Sure, of course, I can change query for the same result.
How would you write?

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this query as:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(col_a) FROM tab_a WHERE user_id=1) -
    (SELECT SUM(col_b) FROM tab_b WHERE user_id=1)
```

I have never used Doctrine, but all you would need to do is two separate sum queries, and take their difference.